# Excel - Looks in a table for instances of matching data from another table and copying them in order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am hoping the example I show below helps my conundrum

[image: Example]
I am looking to add a formula into cell I24:I44 that looks in the **Entry Table's** Nominal Code column for any entries that match the list of codes in the **Lookup table** and then returns the first instance, second etc.

I've tried Index and Match but I think I need to use Vlookup instead but I have only been able to do it for a specific code, rather than any.
I'm currently using `=INDEX(A3:A20,MATCH(I4:I18,I4:I18,0),0)`
Any help on this would save my hair being pulled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the FILTER function in your Excel, it will do the job best.
However, if you limit yourself to just checking the codes, then there will be 3 items compatible. If you're aiming for two, then you should compare accounts as well.
A dynamic formula for `E24` in the first case:

```
=FILTER(IF(ISBLANK($E$3:$O$20),"",$E$3:$O$20),COUNTIF($A$3:$A$21,$I$3:$I$20))
```

In the second:

```
=FILTER(IF(ISBLANK($E$3:$O$20),"",$E$3:$O$20),COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$21,$I$3:$I$20,$B$3:$B$21,$J$3:$J$20))
```

The fragment:
`IF(ISBLANK($E$3:$O$20),"",$E$3:$O$20)`

is used to mask the zeros that would be displayed when the source cells are empty.
[image: Filter codes]

Comment: Thanks that sorted it. I never would have thought to use FILTER. Bravo and thanks again